# IKImageBrowserView inside NSScrollView in InterfaceBuilder issue?

Tags: xcode, interface-builder, nsscrollview

If I set Custom Class of `NSScrollView` to `IKImageBrowserView` in Interface Builder I can't see `IKImageBrowserView` properties in Attributes Inspector pane (and also bindings in bindings pane), instead there are `NSView` properties. But in ImageKitDemo example there is `NSScrollView` with `IKImageBrowserView` inside and in Attributes Inspector correct properties are shown. How did they do that? Are there any magic words?

Xcode 4.3.1

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The correct (and easy) way to do this is:

1. Drag an `IKImageBrowserView` into your window
2. Select the `IKImageBrowserView`
3. Go to [menu] `Editor` > `Embed in` > `Scrollview`

---

**Update:** Apple now [suggests](https://developer.apple.com/reference/quartz/ikimagebrowserview) to switch to `NSCollectionView` and (as @ julia_v points out) the class is not available in the objects library any more.

Comment: Excuse me, but drag from where? Can't find it in objects library.

Comment: @julia_v No worries, you're right, there's isn't there... A lot of things changed since 2012, one of those was the introduction of `NSCollectionView` (which [Apple states](https://developer.apple.com/reference/quartz/ikimagebrowserview) that we should use instead now)

Comment: thank you. I found it possible to copy this object from an old project's .xib and insert in a new one though... and then moved to `NSCollectionView `.